# Bring an image in front of a graphics - Simple Way-

Tags: java

I'm stuck with an issue in my program. I'm working on a little pac man project. Basically I'm trying to display the pills on the maze which is already drawn.

So the maze is a g2 graphics, I used a simple txt file to convert the numeric maze into a graphic one.

What I'm telling to the program is as the following :

- if you hit a '1' you put a road (black),
- if you hit a '2' you put a pill(import pill image), and
- if you hit a '3' you put a super pill(import superpill image)

Here is the part of the code which is needed for more details

```
@Override
public void draw(Graphics g) {

    for(int y=0;y<nbLin;y++){

        for(int x=0;x<nbCol;x++){

            if(charAt(x,y)!='0'){
                g.fillRect(x*STEP-14,y*STEP-14,28,28); // put a road
            }
            if(charAt(x,y)=='2'){
                g.drawImage(pill.getSubimage(0,0,28,28),x*STEP-14,y*STEP-14,null);// put a pill

            }

            if(charAt(x,y)=='3'){
                g.drawImage(superpill.getSubimage((frame2/2)*30,0,28,28),x*STEP-14,y*STEP-14,null); //put a super pill

            }
        }
    }
```

If I take this line :

```
g.fillRect(x*STEP-14,y*STEP-14,28,28)
```

The reason why I multiply the coordinate by `STEP` is just because I multiply the screen size by the same `STEP` so I have to change all the new points coordinates by the same proportions I believe.

The reason why I subtract 14 is due to the size of pacman which is 28 so, i just subtract half of the pacman size from each point in order to center the `road` (Rect) around him.

Don't pay attention to the `subImage` part it's not really relevant in that case.

A solution for that problem I think would be to bring all the pill images to the front. Problem is I don't find a simple way to do that.

Comment: Do you draw the background before drawing the pills?

Comment: "The solution for that problem" - you did not state what the problem was.

Comment: I guess the answer to that question is both before  and after due to the maze.txt structure for instance when the programm import a pill he will fill the background right after if it hits a '1' wich happens 90%

Answer (score 0):

The solution for my problem was simple i thought it would be nice to share it with you if someones meets the same issue you just have to put an other loop in order to draw the images basically i was filling rectangles at the same time that i was printing the images so i just had to seperate the two operations in two different loops